# What is the difference about BIOS, UEFI, Bootloader, Uboot and GRUB?

Tags: linux, bios, grub, uefi, bootloader

I want to better understand a few things.

1. What is the difference about BIOS and UEFI?
2. In PC, there is BIOS and Bootloader (such as GRUB).

But why is there no BIOS in the embedded system (most often is ARM architecture), only bootloader (probably Uboot)?

Comment: what do you mean by `BIOS`? ... are you talking about the menus?

Comment: @jsotola,I am talking about the computer startup details.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/708196/what-is-difference-between-u-boot-and-bios/708420#708420

Answer (score 0):

Well, BIOS was a *specific* implimentation of a firmware used in early x86 systems by IBM, then cloned. UEFI was its replacement, and PCs *always* have had a common standard platform.

There have been other, standard firmware standards like [openboot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Firmware), which I believe some apple x86 boxen, and things like SGI ran, and essentially let you bring up a fuller OS, while having many of the features we see on UEFI.

UEFI *simply* happens to be the firmware standard modern systems use, replacing the old BIOS standard. There's no reason you couldn't build a arm, mips or risc V system off it.

It just so happens most arm systems don't really use a standard hardware platform, nor need the same configurability that a 'PC' or 'Server' system needs and the firmware is built for the platform.

There's no reason you couldn't run UEFI on an arm system if the need existed, and I'm sure that desktop arm boxen might be built around that

Uboot, grub et al *do* need to be brought up by firmware. Embedded systems just tend to use uboot cause they're resource constrained and uboot is a lot smaller than alternatives. They don't need to pick an os or kernel to run, and chances are you have a system that's compiled to fit a need. You generally want an embedded system fast and light, rather than flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your explain. So, why is there no BIOS or UEFI in the embedded sysytem?

Comment: cause you'd compile firmware with the settings that are needed, and not waste valuable storage on things like a GUI or setting setting screens.